# Strategy for modifying a route parameter dynamically within the app

Tags: relayjs

I'm developing a simple app that fetches the weekly lunch menu from a server.  The query looks something like:

```
query {
  lunchMenu(date: $date) {
    id
    name
    etc.
  }
}
```

I've defined a Route like so:

```
class LunchRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static queries = {
  lunchMenu: () => Relay.QL`
    query {  lunchMenu(date: $date) }
  `,
  };

  static paramDefinitions = {
    date: {required: false},
  };
  static routeName = 'LunchRoute';
}
```

I want the user to be able to select the date within the app via a datepicker and I've developed a LunchBrowser component which does that and renders the lunch menu. In index.js I have:

```
const lunchRoute = new LunchRoute({date: new Date()});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Relay.RootContainer
    Component={LunchBrowser}
    route={lunchRoute}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The question is: how do I communicate a change in the date selection (from the LunchBrowser component) up one level so that I can modify the 'date' parameter in the Route and re-render?

I suppose I could have the LunchBrowser fire off some window event that is caught in index.js that does this, but this seems very wrong in that communication is flowing "up" from a lower-level component outside of React.

Or should I redefine my schema such that `lunchMenu(date: $date)` is pushed down one level? As in:

```
query {
  lunch {
    lunchMenu(date: $date) {
      id
      name
      etc.
    }
  }
}
```

in which case `lunch(date: $date)` can be pushed down into LunchBrowserContainer's fragment and I no longer have to worry about dynamically modifying the Route's parameter.